# What is the best way to deliver notification daily even if the app is killed

Tags: android, notifications, repeatingalarm

I wanted to deliver daily notification at a specified time, I did that but when I close the app from recents, the notification did not delivered at all. I dont know how to figure that out. Can someone please suggest me what is the best way to deliver the notification even if the app is closed (not force closed) or the device is booted, the notification must be at the exact time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code,

The alarmreciever class,

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

String meaning;
String word;

Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

 this.context=context;
    FileIO fileIO=new FileIO(context);

    String res=fileIO.readFile("daily_word");
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(res,"---");
   word = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
    meaning = stringTokenizer.nextToken();

    fileIO.writeFile(word+"---"+meaning,"sent_word");

    int ch= word.charAt(0);
    if(ch>=65 && ch<=90)
    {
    }
    else
        ch=ch-32;

    word=(char)ch+word.substring(1);

    produceNotificatioon(context);

    System.out.println("<> ALARM RECEiVE");



}




public void produceNotificatioon(Context context)
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
            .setContentTitle("Word of the Day")
            .setContentText("Today's Word is "+word)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_2);

    Intent myintent = new Intent(context,WordOfTheDay.class);

    TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

    taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(WordOfTheDay.class);
    taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(myintent);



    PendingIntent pendingIntent=taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(102,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());


}
```

}

The setAlarm method,

```
public void setAlarm()
{
    Intent myintent=new Intent(this,AlarmReciever.class);


    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);


    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,101,myintent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, NotificationTime.getInt("hour", 12));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, NotificationTime.getInt("min", 0));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


    if(calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance()))
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);


    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY
            , pendingIntent);


    System.out.println("ALARM SET STATUS");
}
```

Below is some of the oncreate code,

```
            if(checkFirstRun()) {

            createAlert createAlert=new createAlert(this);
            createAlert.createDialog();



            setDaily_word();

            setAlarm();
            System.out.println("ALARM SET STATUS on FIRST RUN");
        }
```

I am setting alarm if it is the apps first RUn, Otherwise I am setting alarm either using timepicker of using the service onCreate() method

Here is the service class,

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {


    System.out.println("class Service started");
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {

    System.out.println("class Service on TaskRemoved");
    //   setAlarm();

    //  onCreate();
    System.out.println("class Service on Alarm reset  oncreate");
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    System.out.println("class Service created");
   setAlarm();   // this work if I start my application just after it is being cleared from recent apps
    super.onCreate();
}
}
```

here is my manifest file,
I am using only these permissions

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
.....
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever" android:process=":remote"/>
    <service android:name=".ServiceClass"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If notification is [FCM/GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging) it would range between 0-15 min, the nature of the push delivery cannot guarantee exact timing.
2. If notification is produced locally by your app at some point, you can use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule [an intent to start BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int)) to trigger [creation of notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html).

Comment: i already created alarm with broadcast receiver. But the problem is that the alarm does not show up when the app is cleared from the recent apps or killed. I can reset the alarm whenever the app is opened. But till the time the app is removed from the recents the alarm does not work.

Comment: could you update your question with example of your code how you schedule intent using alarm manager and how do you handle it? That should help to make question clearer.

Comment: could you try to remove `android:process=":remote"` and define `android:exported="true"`. Rather than that can't see problem.

Comment: Okk will try , but what will it do anyway??

Comment: Is there a reason you run it in separate process? Just a shot in a dark.

Comment: I thought may be creating another process won't shutdown the alarm.

Comment: Ok, now if i add export attrib. Does the alarm won't  be killed if the app is swiped away from recent apps?

Comment: Alarm should not be killed if app swiped or not, because alarm is scheduled on system service not in your app. Export just signals system it is exported to outside world.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Not sure it will help, but I would try play around, add more logs, to see where it cuts off, that might lead you to a root cause. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, still it didn't worked. Please would you mind trying this code yourself.